# How to save ACF custom fields data when a plugin triggers the WordPress save_post hook

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a plugin which is triggering the `save_post` hook of WordPress upon creating posts. The plugin is a scrape plugin. I need added some code to `functions.php` file which should save the data once the `save_post` hook is triggered by this plugin.

What my code is doing:

1. Fetches the data from one of the fields `howtoapply`.
2. Puts the data after formatting it as required into the new field `application_email` using some PHP code as you can see below.

Right now, without using the `save_post` hook, the acf field `application_email` data is not saved in the postmeta table. However, upon clicking edit the post (which refreshes the post), the data is saved without even having to click on the Update button.

How do I run this code when the `save_post` WordPress hook is triggered by the plugin because only then can the plugin save my custom fields data alongside the data being crawled.

The code:

```
add_filter('acf/load_field/name=application_email', function( $field ) {
        $howtoapply = get_field( 'howtoapply' );

        
            $apply_link = get_field( 'howtoapply' );
            $link       = $apply_link;
            libxml_use_internal_errors( true );

            $dom = new DOMDocument();
            @$dom->loadHTML( $link );
            $dom->loadHTML( $link );
            foreach ( $dom->getElementsByTagName( 'a' ) as $a ) {
            }

            function cfDecodeEmail( $encodedString ) {
                $k = hexdec( substr( $encodedString, 0, 2 ) );
                for ( $i = 2,$email = '';$i < strlen( $encodedString ) - 1;$i += 2 ) {
                    $email .= chr( hexdec( substr( $encodedString, $i, 2 ) ) ^ $k );
                }
                return $email;
            }

            if ( ! is_null( $a ) && is_object( $a ) ) {
                $field['value'] = cfDecodeEmail( $a->getAttribute( 'data-cfemail' ) );
                $GLOBALS[ $field['value'] ] = cfDecodeEmail( $a->getAttribute( 'data-cfemail' ) );

                if (!add_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'application_email', $field['value'])) {
                //update_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'application_email', $field['value']);

                // Update field in database
                update_field( 'field_123456', $field['value'] );
            }
                
            } else {
                
            }
        
        return $field;
    }
);
```

Comment: ACF stores more info than just the key=value pair in the meta data tables, there is also an entry containing the interval field key for each value that you store. `add_post_meta` does not create that second record, so you won't see the field value when using ACF functions, until the post gets re-saved (and ACF gets to do its thing via its own hooks.) Instead of `add_post_meta`, use `update_field` when you want to store values for use with ACF.

Comment: I am using the ```add_post_meta``` as a condition. You want me to change the condition to use ```update_field```? I have no clue how to tweak it the way you mean.

Answer (score 0):

You can use like this, please update your code:

```
update_field( 'field_123456', $field['value'], {post_id} );
```

Please try this and let me know if you find any issues

Thank you.

Comment: I added the ```post_id``` but nothing happens.

Comment: Have you added the actual integer post id?

Comment: This is how i did it ```update_field( 'field_123456', $field['value'], $post_id );```

Comment: Can you please replace $post_id with get_the_ID()?

Comment: Please let me know if it's still not work for you.

Comment: Still did not work.

Comment: This will work when you hit the update button:

Comment: `function my_function_on_save_post( $post_id ) {
$gethowtoapply = get_post_meta($post_id, 'howtoapply', true);
update_post_meta($post_id, 'application_email', $gethowtoapply);
}
add_action( 'save_post', 'my_function_on_save_post' );`

Comment: Haven't been able to get it to work. For some reason, I have to first open the post for editing for the meta to save. Somehow the edit post action is triggering the code to run. As long as I am within the ```&action=edit``` the code is run. Tried to use save_post but still doesn't work. As you can see from my code, we are passing data from one field ```get_field( 'howtoapply' )``` to another ```application_email```. Is it possible that the field is only being loaded with the new value late when everything has run. Run out of options here.